# Can multiple Windows installations share applications?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

Can I have two installations of Windows 7 (on separate partitions of a hard drive) share applications? E.g. when prompted for installation path - choose a third partition and have both Windows installations use those application files?

I'm not referring to app data and the like, I mean the actual application files. And, of course, I'm not referring to self-standing applications, I mean those that have to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question, multiple Windows installations should be able to share applications, however, I don't believe Windows support such feature ever.

That being said, I has always been trying to do this despite not being supported by Windows. This is what I do.

- For every Windows system, I create at least three disks. The C: is my OS disk, the D: is my app disk, and E: is my data disk.
- For all the application, I install them into `D:\Program Files`, instead of `C:\Program Files`
- This does not means that the installed application is ready to use in another Windows instance, because for those Windows those application "do not exist" because they are not installed yet from the Windows point of view. Also, most application installation will write something to the register.
- However, you can do the same thing in another Windows instances, installing application into `D:\Program Files`, instead of `C:\Program Files`, and choose the same location as the previously installed
- The effect is that you will have the exact same installation on `D:` in `D:\Program Files`, thus saving space for multiple copy of same installations.
- However, some Windows application doesn't make you life any easy, they will complain about the directory or files are already there. In such case, don't worry, just delete the previous copy and install another. Because the installation would be exactly the same, the late installed copy can be used by the previous Windows instances just fine.
- Once again, all that you are saving is the application installation space. You will have single installation on `D:` for all your Windows systems, instead of letting them having their own each
- On `C:` drive, you don't have much control because it's totally Windows regime, you still have to have multiple copies of register, etc, etc. Windows is the worst OS to share applications, even if you have done installation with one user, Windows will most often trigger another installation if you login as a different user and try to use the installed 
  application.
- BTW, I actually don't install them into `D:\Program Files` but to `D:\Programs` instead, because long file names and space in them will sometimes give me headache, and I want to avoid headaches as much as I can.

HTH